# Git proper way to commit changes when server has changes

Tags: git

I just want to know the proper way of commit to Git repository. Suppose that I have changes in my local for some files which has changes in server version as well (there is obvious conflicts). I hope that I have to pull the server changes first. And when some conflicts shows I have to manually resolve the conflicts and then I will have to commit and push the changes again. Please advise. I am little confused about the need of pop save. Do I need to pop save in this scenario?

Comment: well, isn't `git pull` doing what you are asking for? Or, if your **"commit and push the changes again"** means "submitting each of your changes with remote side changes included", then git fetch + rebase is what you need to do I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

You will always need to do a git pull before you do a git push. Git won't let you push your changes unless your repo has all the new work.

If there are any merge conflicts you can simple resolve them and then commit those merge conflicts in a new commit.

At that point you just do a git push.

If you have been doing work and have code changes that have not been committed this is where opinion and problems come in. A lot of people will do a git stash before dealing with merge conflicts and then a git pop after the final git push. If you aren't careful you may end up committing new code changes that you didn't intend. However, with proper testing, release branching, and development practices this shouldn't happen.

You commands should look something like this.

```
git pull
# Manually resolve any conflicts, hopefully there are few
git add conflict_file
git commit -m "Fixed merge conflicts with my new devwork"
git push
```

Answer (score 4):

These are your options.  Start by committing your changes.  If you don't commit your changes, Git will not let you merge the changes from upstream (you won't be able to see the new versions from the server).

1. Fetch, merge, then (eventually) push.  Fetch and merge is the same thing as `git pull`.
2. Fetch, rebase, then (eventually) push.  Fetch and rebase is the same thing as `git pull --rebase`.

Remember that anything you haven't pushed yet, you can change locally without consequences.

Note that `push` will fail if you haven't incorporated the server's latest changes into your local repository.  It sounds like this is exactly what you were hoping for.  That is, as long as you avoid using `push --force`.